# Laravel route doesn't go to correct controller method

Tags: laravel, routes

I have those routes

```
Route::get('/account/{id}','AccountsController@show')->name('account.show');
Route::get('/account/create','AccountsController@create')->name('account.create');
```

And those methods in my AccountsController

```
public function show(){

    echo 'SHOW';

}
public function create(){

    echo 'CREATE';

}
```

And when I use route account/create it return "SHOW". Any idea why it doesn't go to the correct method ? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `{id}` part in the first route is a wildcard, so any value will match the first route, number or string. You just need to **switch the order** of the routes.

Comment: I did't know about that, and now im felling little stupid. Thank you!